# Facebook return ID and me.name

Tags: perl, facebook-graph-api

I am really lost with these two problems with Facebook API...

All has been working fine posting to user walls, but I have one client with a page. The page was created from scratch, not via themselves as a user - ie they did not login and create a page they just started from the Facebook welcome screen>create page.

There page works fine, however,

1) Our system is submitting a post via API and receiving an ID in return (eg {"id":"123456_123456"} back from Facebook - this tells me facebook has accepted it and has given me an ID for the post.

However, the post DOES NOT appear on the page it relates to (and I have checked where it is submitting it to and it is the correct User ID). This system has been working fine for all other users.

2) When the login occurs via Javascript for this user, we get an empty value for "me.name" (we get me.email etc, just no name)

Is all this normal, or do pages have a different technique to posting and retrieving data?

Answer (score 2):

Email is a private data of facebook user , It is a permission issue what you are encountering

The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended permissions on the email field.

After logging in .

This is how facebook api works , w.r.t revealing private data of its users

Comment: That wasn't what I asked, I can do that easily with document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_groups'});});

Comment: The problem I am experiencing in more details is that we submit a JSON  encoded post that contains the access token, links, caption, etc...

We have hundreds of users that submit blogs, posts or add events via our system and they all get posted OK - and in all cases we receive
{"id":"123456_123456"} (for example) back that means Facebook accepted the post (as that contains the post ID). However, this is the only customer that has created a page from scratch (from the main login screen) NOT as an existing  user that has clicked Create Page. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: However this causes a strange issue. We receive an success ID back for the post our system submits - but the post does not appear on the page.

Comment: Facebook returns success , but still that is not the only phase that your application can go , meaning you need to some how provide means to ask for permission , try catching the exception and debug edit the post if you get genine exception messages

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this one, I don't doubt the ability of anyone here - perhaps my question is still being misunderstood...

Some Facebook pages (especially business pages) where the page hasn't been created by an existing user are different to Facebook groups and user pages. You cannot just submit using an short ot long term access token.

You have to call facebook as http://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_PAGE/accounts with your token first.

Facebook returns a list of pages, each with their own unique ID and a token for each.

You then grab the token for the page you want then resubmit with the page ID and that pages OWN token - and voila it posts to it!

Their are still bugs with Facebook as I found. It says on one business page I created for a client "Use Facebook as ." - ie the name is missing before the "." - it should say "Use Facebook as MYNAME."

This introduced another problem with the JS FB.login because the name of the person returns undefined. I had to verify their Email instead - other wise it says "You are logged in as ."

I think its because FB lets you create a page from scratch, as a new user, and without logging in as yourself - then some values are not being set and it messes up.

Perhaps may help someone...